# SQL insert distinct data with sequence

Tags: sql, oracle

Here is the query:

```
    for i in ids.FIRST .. ids.LAST loop
    insert into myTable
        (objid, id, name )

    (select
        values.nextval, ids(i), table2.name

    from  table2

    where table2.id = ids(i) 
    );
   end loop;
```

I want to use a distinct on ids as they have redundant values but using distinct with sequence is not directly possible. I know I can wrap a subquery in the from clause but have not been able to do the same without errors :/

Comment: You have duplicates in your PL/SQL collection? Can't you remove them from that?

Comment: How do you select `cl.name` from table2?  I don't think column names could have a dot in them.

Comment: excuse me for the error in query; fixed it. I had typed the query here and hence the induced error.

Comment: Can't remove the duplicates from the collection as they are linked with 2 different accounts. The database has been setup in a way (before I joined) that two different accounts can be linked to the same id.

Answer (score 0):

Well, can you do this instead-

```
FOR rec IN (SELECT DISTINCT column_value
              FROM TABLE(CAST(ids As *Type name*))
LOOP
    INSERT INTO myTable (objid, id, name )
    SELECT values.nextval, rec.column_value, table2.name
      FROM table2
     WHERE table2.id = rec.column_value;
END LOOP;
```

`COLUMN_VALUE` is a [pseudo column](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/pseudocolumns004.htm#SQLRF51142) and you will need to know the "Type name" of the collection `ids`. Also, the table type must be must be an attribute data type - in other words the type must be declared at the schema level rather than locally - which restricts this to VARRAY table types and NESTED TABLE types i.e. you can't use  associative arrays.